# Can we find a lower bound for $P(V>1)$ when we know $EV=1$ and $P(V \le 1- \eta) \ge \delta? V \ge 0$ is non-constant.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $V \ge 0$ be a non-negative, non-constant, random variable and assume that we know $EV=1$ and $P(V \le 1- \eta) \ge \delta.$ I'm trying to see if I can find a lower bound for $P(V>1),$ in terms of $\eta, \delta?$

Intuitively, speaking, since $EV=1,$ it stands to reason that $P(V>1)$ and $P(V<1)$ both must be strictly positive as $V$ is *non-constant*. Now in this problem: we've a *lower* bound on $P(V \le 1- \eta),$ but does this guarantee a ***lower*** bound for the probability of the "other side", namely $P(V>1),$ which intuitively seems correct as *this probability has to be big enough to balance the expectation of $V$ to be equal to $1.$* Intuitively, if this probability is too small, then $P(V>1)$ is close to $0,$ so $P(V<1)$ is close to $1,$ and as a result, it seems the $EV$ will be strictly less than $1.$

**EDIT:** Is it possible to have this kind of uniform lower bound if we instead work with a **uniformly bounded** or [**uniformly integrable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability) family of random variables $\{V_{\epsilon}\}?$ If yes, what'd be the bound?

Answer (score 1):

Unless $V$ is bounded, $P(V > 1)$ can still be arbitrarily small.  For fixed $0 < \eta, \delta < 1$ let $0 < \varepsilon < 1-\delta$.  Then define $V = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ with probability $\varepsilon$ and $V = 0$ with probability $1-\varepsilon$.  Then $\mathbb{E}[V] = 1$ and $P(V \le 1-\eta) = 1-\varepsilon > \delta$, but $P(V > 1) = \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you - that's nice insight into checking what seems counterintuitive at first. I do have a follow-up question. We notice that the family $\{V_{\epsilon}\}$ is not only uniformly bounded, but also not uniformly integrable, as $lim_{K} \to \infty sup_{\epsilon > 0} E[V_{\epsilon} I(| V_{\epsilon} |>K)]=1 \nrightarrow.0.$ This makes me wonder if we can relax the uniform boundedness of $\{V_{\epsilon}\}$ to just uniform integrability?

Comment: I'm also editing my question keeping what was before exactly as before but asking a similar question about uniformly integrable family.